# Adding an invoice id when creating a payment with paypal rest api

Tags: paypal

With the classic api you can pass an internal invoice id to paypal to associate with a payment

[here is the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_SOAP/#paymentdetailstype)

Specifically :

> InvoiceID
>
> (Optional) Your own invoice or tracking number.
>
> Important: The value you specify is available only if the transaction
>   includes a purchase. This field is ignored if you set up a billing
>   agreement for a recurring payment that is not immediately charged.
>
> Note PayPal recommends using the InvoiceID field to associate
>   transactions with your internal tracking IDs or invoice numbers;
>   populating the invoice ID field will help you pull transaction
>   information at a later date using only your internal ID.
>
> Character length and limitations: 256 single-byte alphanumeric
>   characters

However, I can't seem to find a way to do this with the rest api.  All the invoice id's are created dynamically.

[Here is the rest api documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#transaction-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now supported by the PayPal REST APIs, the field is called invoice_number, part of the transaction object. Refer to https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/release-notes/#updates-for-5-august-2014 and https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/explore-payment-capabilities/

Comment: But this is "Only supported when the payment_method is set to paypal" according to the docs.  What about for card/vault payments?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can do it when using the actual [Invoicing API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#create-an-invoice) in REST.  The notes for the number parameter are:

> Unique number that appears on the invoice. If left blank will be
>   auto-incremented from the last number. 25 characters max.

Sounds like that's where you'd enter your own if you have one.

I'm not seeing anything outside of that, though.  This sort of thing is why I haven't rushed to the REST API.  They've got a long ways to go to catch up to the classic API, and they don't do anything that classic doesn't do.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that's not the invoice id, that's a different field.  The classic api also has that field.  I need the actual invoice id parameter.

Comment: So why not just stick with classic?

Comment: I'm dealing with third parties that implement the api, moving to the classic api will cost a lot of money.

Comment: Not with this particular vendor.  This one is using .net.